# Merge [Headset] and [Headphones]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/headset) has a three sentence tag summary and 163 questions.  [headphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/headphones) has no tag summary, and 77 questions.  Should [headphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/headphones) redirect to [headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/headset)?  The questions of both tags are almost all also tagged with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), which implies neither is being used for any unexpected purposes.

Comment: Why are either of these tags?  Can you really be an expert in headsets or headphones?

Comment: @bluefeet Maybe a headset expert can show us the difference between headset and headphones :)

Comment: The difference IRL is that Headphones have micrphones in addition to speakers.  However, as far as _code_ goes, they're pretty much identical to either speakers.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think you have it backwards there, head *sets* have microphones, head *phones* tend to have only speakers. :)